# What is the recommended way to detect that a Control+some-key has been pressed?

Tags: c++, windows

Let's say that I desire to catch the **Control-A** combination.

This is my code so far, in a Windows Hook function:

```
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam);
if (kbdStruct.vkCode == 0x41)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("A has been pressed!"), TEXT("key pressed"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Since the users press the Control key first (and leave it pressed for many milliseconds), my Keyboard Hook above should initially ignore that key, correct? I guess that I need to be on the lookout for the letter "A" and as soon as it is detected, I should check the status of the modifier, Control key?

Maybe there is some **AND** mask for this?

Addition: Let's say that I need a Control-B or Control-C or Control-D all the way to Control-Z. Perhaps what I need is Alt-A, or Alt-B, or Alt-C... all the way to Alt-Z

How do I conflate the 2 partial matches? (the Alphabetic key plus the modifier key).

Comment: The `vkCode` member should contain a bitwise combination of virtual key flags. If the control key is depressed, that will be one of the flags included. Along with whatever alphanumeric key is depressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
LRESULT __stdcall Process_Ctl_A(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam);
        if (kbdStruct.vkCode == 0x41 && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Control-A combination has been pressed!"), TEXT("key pressed"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please, no keyboard hook DLLs - that injects code into processes that aren't designed to handle keyboard hooks and creates system instability.

Are you trying to catch "CTRL+A" because you are trying to implement something like "Select All" within your app.  If that's the case, you just need a [keyboard accelerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to catch this keyboard sequence when you app has focus.

But if you need to catch You should try looking at the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.  I think that should meet your needs if you need a global hook.  But be warned - I'm not sure what happens if you register CTRL+A and the application is using that key combination for something like "select all".

Comment: From a simple test with RegisterHotkey, it seems that my small program  would consume the keypress and the active program (notepad) would not select all.

Comment: @Matt - thanks for confirming. I hope the OP uses a keyboard combination that isn't commonly used. (i.e. be a good windows citizen).

Comment: My application is an Acrobat plugin which implements the "copy" half of a "copy&paste" facility. The **only** keyboard combination that makes sense to **Select All** the page content is Control-A.

Comment: @swiss_programmer - hopefully you can use the keyboard accelerator functions (link above) instead of declaring a system-wide override of CTRL+A.